# How to get content size of UINavigationController?

Tags: objective-c

I'm trying to get content size of UINavigationController. 
I can get content size which considered just navigationbar's height using like this way.

```
CGSize contentSize = self.view.bounds.size;
```

But I want to get it considered navigationbar and toolbar's height.

How to get it?

========  comment after question ==================== 
Oh~ my mistake. 
 
You can get frame size considered two by above way.
===============================================

landscape

[image]

portrait

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you want is the top view controller of the navigation controller in question, it's frame has the size you want:

```
CGSize contentSize = nav.topViewController.frame.size;
```

Comment: I believe you meant:  `nav.topViewController.view.frame.size;`

Comment: Infact it depends on your view hierarchy, if your bottom bar is part of your `topViewController` the return size will include bottom bar.

Comment: this will return size including top navigation bar, which might have different height based on device and it's orientation